# Transforming python variable into string

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a variable `username = "jag"`, and jag is stored as a string.

Later on down the code, I need to use the `username` variable here like this: `db[(username)] = 1`

However, that line of code only excepts input like this `db["jag"] = 1`

How can I get around this issue by "pre-converting" the variable before use?

The package that I use is from `from replit import db`

Comment: `db[username] = 1` should work perfectly fine.

Comment: You should include the exact error you are getting in your question.

Comment: I have tried `db[username] = 1`, and that does not work either. I seems that it needs to be in a "---" format to work. Please advise.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the [help] and [ask]. Your problem is not clear. What *exactly* is the problem? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see now that `db[username] = 1` works perfectly fine. I had a function hanging out that I did not see.